# Notify changes of Firestore data in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, notifydatasetchanged

In my App there is a fragment that contain an Expandable RecyclerView get data from firebase firestore, every Item  in it have a button that when clicked change some data in Firestore that affect on the items some way. 
Now the problem is: when run the app and click the button the data don't change till I refresh the fragment..

fragment.java:

```
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
final String UserId = currentUser.getUid();

final RecyclerView recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

db.collectionGroup("Id").whereEqualTo("id", UserId).get()
  .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < QuerySnapshot > () {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < QuerySnapshot > task) {
        final List < Company > Parent = new ArrayList < > ();

        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document: task.getResult()) {
            final List < String > grades = (List < String > ) document.get("tagsG");

            CollectionReference collectionReference =
                document.getReference().getParent();
            final List < Product > Child = new ArrayList < > ();
            for (int i = 0; i < grades.size(); i++) {
                final String gg = grades.get(i);
                collectionReference.document(UserId).collection(gg).whereEqualTo("approvedStd",0).get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < QuerySnapshot > () {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < QuerySnapshot > task) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document: task.getResult()) {
                                String name = document.getString("std_name");
                                String sub = document.getString("std_subject");
                                String region = document.getString("std_region");
                                Child.add(new Product(name, sub, region, gg));
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }
            Parent.add(new Company("new", Child));
            productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(Parent);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(productAdapter);
        }
    }
});
return root;
```

ViewHolder.java

```
public class ProductViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder {
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    private FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    private String UserId = currentUser.getUid();
    private TextView name;
    private TextView sTextView;
    private TextView region;
    private Button addButton;
    private String phoneOfstd;
    private String grade;
    private ProductAdapter productAdapter;

    public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        sTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sub);
        region = itemView.findViewById(R.id.region);
    }

    public void bind(Product product) {
        name.setText(product.name);
        sTextView.setText(product.sub);
        region.setText(product.region);
        grade = product.grade;

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                CollectionReference questionsRef = db.collection("Teachers checked").document("courses").collection("Id");
                DocumentReference docRef = questionsRef.document(UserId).collection(grade).document(phoneOfstd);
                docRef.update("approvedStd", 1);
                productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

ProductAdapter.java

```
public class ProductAdapter extends
 ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter < CompanyViewHolder, ProductViewHolder > {
    public ProductAdapter(List < ? extends ExpandableGroup > groups) {
        super(groups);
    }

    @Override
    public CompanyViewHolder onCreateGroupViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.expandable_recyclerview_company, parent, false);
        return new CompanyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.expandable_recyclerview_product, parent, false);
        return new ProductViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindChildViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group, int childIndex) {
        final Product product = (Product) group.getItems().get(childIndex);
        holder.bind(product);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindGroupViewHolder(CompanyViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group) {
        final Company company = (Company) group;
        holder.bind(company);
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

I tried to write *productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*  in the fragment after *recyclerView.setAdapter(productAdapter);* but the app crashes and the logcat shows this error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to
>   invoke virtual method 'void 
>   com.example.exercise.ExpandableRecyclerView.ProductAdapter. 
>   notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference

Comment: try adding this line in the fragment productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @MarsadMaqsood Can you tell me where to write it exactly? Because I tried but the app crashes

Comment: In fragment below
```
Parent.add(new Company("new", Child));
                        productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(Parent);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(productAdapter);
```
```
productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope this works

Comment: I suggest you to use this library

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.2.0'

Comment: take a look at: https://github.com/Marsad-Ch/firestore

Comment: @MarsadMaqsood FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.exercise.ExpandableRecyclerView.ProductAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be your error here `docRef.update("approvedStd", 1);
                productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

you update the object in firestore but you don't implement EventListener  to retrieve data after any change occurs so you have tow option one to update this opject in arrayList  and call notifydatasetChanged  or add Snapshotlistener to retrieve data after any change performed

Answer (score 1):

First, your `productAdapter` equal `null` because you didn't assign any value to it, you should pass a reference to your adapter into the view holder.

Second, the main problem is you need to update the view when you click a view in the item.

1- handle changes when binding the view in the bind method.

2- when you click on the btn or the view you should update the object by the changes that you need to display.

3- if the changes affect the current item only use

```
notifyItemChanged(position, object)
```

if it's affect on many items you should use

```
notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Ex:
if you have checkbox and you need to make it works in your recycler.

1- bind the checkbox in the bind method

```
checkbox.setChecked(product.isSelected());
```

2- at checked change event we will update product object

```
product.setSelected(isChecked);
```

3- at the end of the checked change event

```
notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition(), product);
```

Answer (score 0):

U can put a function that read your data in your adapter to make sure that your data is updated. I can not see the code of your adapter here but try this and let me know if it's solved or not.

Comment: Can you explain more? I edited the Q and added the code of Adapter..